# MySql Linked Server from MSSQL server?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have established linked server connection, it is working fine but got some problem with 2 fields, `Col1` which got `datatype varchar(10000)` and also same for `Col2 varchar(10000)` from source. when I queried:

```
select 
    * 
from 
    [MySQL_Linked]...SorceTbl
```

I got the below error:

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MySQL_Linked"
>   returned message "Requested conversion is not supported.".
>
> Msg 7341,
>
> > Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Cannot get the current row value of column
> >     "[MySQL_Linked]...[MyDB].SorceTbl" from OLE DB provider
> >     "MSDASQL" for linked server "MySQL_Linked".

I tried with `Cast and Convert` but no use. any help?

someone marked this quesion as duplicate but the difference is

> his solution is changed data type at source but for me I don't have
>   permissions to change data types from source.

Comment: Hi @Matt Gibson, you are right but his solution is changed data type at source but for me I don't have permissions to change data types from source. Thanks

Comment: @user3583912 . . . I think the second answer provides a reasonable solution.  You may be able to even wrap the logic in a view.

Comment: I'm wondering if casting to a `VARCHAR(MAX)` or `NVARCHAR(MAX)` might work? (If you try that and it works, you should add that as an answer to the earlier question...)

Comment: Hi @Matt Gibson, I also tried `VARCHAR(MAX)` but still same error. I also updated latest MySQL Driver as well but no use. I really don't know what to do? Thanks

Comment: Could you show us your code for an attempted cast, and confirm that you're getting the same error message as you were originally? I've voted to re-open, as I think this question may be sufficiently different, plus that question is quite old and some of the advice (e.g. use the obsolete `TEXT` type) isn't that great these days.

Comment: Hi @Matt Gibson, look at the screen shot. Thanks